# Get a Navigational properties with generic Repository Base class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, ef-core-6.0

I have a Repository base class like so:

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> : IRepositoryBase<T> where T : class
{
    protected RepositoryContext RepositoryContext;

    public RepositoryBase(RepositoryContext repositoryContext)
        => RepositoryContext = repositoryContext;

         public IQueryable<T> FindByCondition(Expression<Func<T, bool>> 
    expression, bool trackChanges)
            {
                return !trackChanges ?
                  RepositoryContext.Set<T>().Where(expression).AsNoTracking() :
                            RepositoryContext.Set<T>().Where(expression);
            }
}
```

This is working fine to retrieve a single entity. But how can I modify it to retrieve its navigational properties too?

I saw this kind of answer here on Stackoverflow. But I do not know how to apply it to my base class above. Any help, please.

```
    RepositoryContext.Model.GetEntityTypes()
                         .Select(t => new
                         {
                             t.ClrType.Name,
                             NavigationProperties = t.GetNavigations()
.Select(x => x.PropertyInfo)
                     });
```

My query is like so:

```
     public async Task<IEnumerable<Fare>> 
GetAllFaresByUserAsync(string userId, bool trackChanges)
            {
                return await FindByCondition(e => e.UserId.Equals(userId), 
    trackChanges).ToListAsync();
            }
```

The models are like so: I can get the `Fares` collection using my query above. But  `"extras": [],` is the problem here?

`Fare`

```
public class Fare
{
    [Column("FareId")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public decimal? Amount { get; set; }

    public int? Date { get; set; }

    public decimal? FareTips { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Extra>? Extras { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey(nameof(User))]
    public string? UserId { get; set; }

    public User? User { get; set; }


}
```

`Extra`

```
public class Extra
{
    [Column("ExtraId")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is a required field.")]
    public string? Name { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Amount is a required field.")]
    public decimal? Amount { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Fare))]
    public Guid FareId { get; set; }

    public Fare? Fare { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(User))]
    public string? UserId { get; set; }

    public User? User { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Have a look at [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#model-configuration-for-auto-including-navigations). They might help you achieve what you want. Which version of EF Core do you use?

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu Latest ef core with .net 6

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu It is working perfectly fine. Please put it as an answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at [how to configure the model to auto-include navigation properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#model-configuration-for-auto-including-navigations). There's an `AutoInclude` method on the model builder that does this for you automatically.

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Fare>().Navigation(f => f.Extras).AutoInclude();
}
```